# AngularJS nested ng-repeat click & show/hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've done a ton of reading and research on this topic the past few days and have found some good answers, but for some of the answers I question performance and necessity.

My question pertains to nested ng-repeat scopes. I'm wondering what the best way to achieve an "add item" scenario for adding an item to the nested foreach.

### My Code

My HTML is simply 2 `ng-repeat`s and my goal is to be able to add an item to the second (nested) `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="nav" ng-controller="FoodsController as vm">
        <div class="level1" ng-repeat="foods in vm.foodGroups">{{foods.Name}}
            <button type="button" ng-click="vm.addNewFood()">add new food</button>
            <div ng-show="vm.newFoodBeingAdded">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="level2" ng-repeat="food in foods.FoodsInGroup">{{food.Name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Angular controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('FoodsController', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foodGroups = [{
        "Name": "Grains",
            "FoodsInGroup": [{
            "Name": "Wheat"
        }, {
            "Name": "Oats"
        }]
    }, {
        "Name": "Fruits",
            "FoodsInGroup": [{
            "Name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "Name": "Orange"
        }]
    }];

    vm.newFoodBeingAdded = false;

    vm.addNewFood = function () {
        vm.newFoodBeingAdded = true;
    };
});
```

### What *should* happen

The general work flow would be a user clicks an **Add New** button and it shows a text box with a "save" button. The text box & button would be within the parent foreach. Once a user saves the item it would then be added to the nested foreach (that logic isn't shown).

### The issue

The issue is that when I click "Add New Food" (which should just show 1 of the text boxes & save buttons), all of the text boxes show. How do I ensure I am "scoping" this correctly and that only the text box/button within that parent are shown?

#### Possible solution

One answer I found was to create a child controller for each nested item. For example I'd have a `FoodGroupsController` which would manage all the logic for the nested foreach (because there will be a lot more going on than just adding a new item in a real app, so it could be justified).

### jsFiddle

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamez14/dvtofn6L/52/) with the code that currently does not function correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the forked [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4nye648/)

I made just few changes. The fact is that you were binding the `ng-show` with a single var in your controller. It was a show me all or show me nothing possibility.
So the fix it, you have to bind this, in your food item, not in the controller himself.

**Html :**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.addNewFood(foods)">add new food</button>
    <div ng-show="foods.newFoodBeingAdded" class="add-new-food">
       <input type="text" placeholer="add a new food">
       <button type="button">save new food</button>
</div>
```

**Controller :**

```
vm.addNewFood = function (foods) {
    foods.newFoodBeingAdded = true;
};
```

With this code, you pass the food in param of your function, so you can change the boolean of your food only. And then, your `ng-show` is just binding on this boolean.